# How to force the jQuery .change function to catch user selection from an autocomplete objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following text field with an auto complete feature:-

Currently I wrote the folliwng to catch what is inside a textbox :-

```
$("#TextBox").change(function () {

$.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Switch/LoadRelatedIPs")", { searchterm: $("#TextBox").val(), SearchBy: $("#ChoiceTag").prop("checked") ? $("#ChoiceTag").val() : $("#ChoiceName").val(), },

           function (CustomerData) {
```

The problem I am facing is that the `$("#TextBox").val()` inside the getJSON , will only catch the value already inside the text box and not what the user select from an auto complete result. For example in the above  picture the `$("#TextBox").val()` will be v10020 instead of the full text which should be  v100205 ? can anyone advice how to solve this issue ? and i do not want to use the select inside the autocomplete , since in this way i will have duplicate calls one from the .change and the other from the autocomplete select function ?

Comment: How do you navigate through the autocomplete? using the mouse to click and/or using the keyboard arrows as well? maybe on any of these events you can udpate the value of the search term using the current highlighted element's value. The change() function will fire for anything in the textbox only.

Comment: Does `console.log($(this).val());` also give you the previous value?

Comment: @YannickY users can navigate the autocomplete either using keyboard arrows or using the mouse ..

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the plugin you are using to do the autocomplete feature? I'm pretty sure this is covered within said documentation via an available event. on select, trigger change, or skip the change all together and use select.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what code is handling the auto complete functionality. You may need to modify your plugin or script to trigger a change event after setting the new value.

```
$("#TextBox").val("New Value").trigger("change");
```

You can also just listen for the various events which fire whenever the text in the input changes:

```
$('#TextBox').on('input propertychange paste', function() {

});
```

Comment: i have the auto complete code, but i did not show it , because it is  not related to my question ...

Comment: but what is the user type the full text or paste it , without selecting an auto complete item..?

Answer (score 0):

The change event fires when the textbox loses focus, which will happen when the user clicks the autocomplete suggestion, which is before the autocomplete javascript fills in the complete value. This is correct behaviour from the change event.

Seems like what you want isn't to execute your code when the Device Resource Tag field changes, but to execute it when a correct (complete) value has been entered. Possible solution: in addition to handling the select event of the autocomplete, when it performs a search, check to see if only one result is returned and it matches what the user has entered, then select that automatically. So in the example above, if the user types out the complete string "V100205", the autocomplete returns one result "V100205". Then you cancel showing the autocomplete and instead execute your code.